# Error plotting array with exponential operation

Tags: julia

I am new to Julia and I am trying to create a plot with the following:

```
    xi2 = range(0,sqrt(6),step=1e-3)
    collect(xi2)
    plot(xi2, 1-xi2^2/6, label="n = 0")
```

When I try this though, I have the error:

```
MethodError: no method matching ^(::StepRangeLen{Float64, Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}, Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}, Int64}, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  ^(::Union{AbstractChar, AbstractString}, ::Integer) at C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.7.0\share\julia\base\strings\basic.jl:721
  ^(::Rational, ::Integer) at C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.7.0\share\julia\base\rational.jl:475
  ^(::Complex{<:AbstractFloat}, ::Integer) at C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.7.0\share\julia\base\complex.jl:839
  ...
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the elements of `xi2` raised to the power of two, so you want element-wise operations using the dot operator:

```
julia> xi2 = range(0,sqrt(6),step=1e-3);

julia> plot(xi2, 1 .- xi2.^2/6, label="n = 0")
```

(The `collect` step was unnecessary, since most array operations can be performed on a range directly. And in case you did want to collect - i.e. allocate memory and make it a full array - you have to assign the result of `collect` to some variable. In your original code, the elements were being collected into an array, but then thrown away since the result wasn't assigned to anything.)

[image: Tada!]